# how to get last non empty column of a series from a date set in SAS

Tags: sql, sas, sas-macro

I'm working on a SAS application and I've a data set as

```
dim_point
rk | ID    | name  | value_0 | value_1 | value_2 | value_3 | value_4
1  | one   |  one  |  val_0  |  val_1  |  val_2  |  val_3  |   .
2  | two   |  two  |  val_0  |  val_1  |  val_2  |    .    |   .
3  | three | three |  val_0  |    .    |    .    |    .    |   .
4  | four  | four  |  val_0  |  val_1  |    .    |    .    |   .
```

I want to get other columns and last non empty column of value as

```
want
rk | ID    | name  |  value
1  | one   |  one  |  val_3
2  | two   |  two  |  val_2
3  | three | three |  val_0
4  | four  | four  |  val_1
```

code that I'm trying to do is

```
proc sql noprint;
create table want as
select rk, ID, name, name as value
from dim_point;

update want 
set value = "";
quit;
```

I don't know how I can update value column with last non empty column value of value_ series?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `coalesce` in reverse order:

```
set value = coalesce(value_4,value_3,value_2,value_1,value_0);
```

You might need to use `coalescec` instead for character variables.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst the `coalesce` solution is fine when you know all the columns, there may be situations where they can either vary, or are significantly more of them.

In that case, you can use an array :

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  array _v{*} value_: ; /* colon operator is a wildcard, loaded in the same order as the input dataset */

  /* Loop backwards over the array, stop when we find a non-missing value */
  do i = dim(_v) to 1 by -1 until (not missing(value)) ;
    if not missing(_v{i}) then value = _v{i} ;
  end ;

  drop i ;
run ;
```